# Use of 'contiguous' for time

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Can I use 'contiguous' for time periods that immediately follow each other, or is usage restricted to geography? For example, would it be correct to say that "session B will be taught contiguously with class A", if I mean to say that class B will start as soon as class A ends?

If that use is not correct, what alternative would you use?

Comment: For the context of time in prison sentences, we usually contrast ***consecutive*** with ***concurrent***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**contiguous** is frequently used in geography as you noted, but can also can be used in the sense of time:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/40227?redirectedFrom=contiguous%20#eid)

> Next in time or order, immediately successive.

As in your sentence with slight modification:

> The two classes will be taught contiguously, starting with X.